# Exercise 1.12 (1) from Revuz and Yor. Proving that the space of absolutely continuous functions in $C$ forms a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

This is Exercise 1.12 (1) from Revuz and Yor's Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion.

Denote by $H$ the subspace of $C([0,1])$ of functions $h$ such that $h(0)=0$, $h$ is absolutely continuous and its derivative $h'$ (which exists a.e.) satisfies 
$$\int_0^1 h'(s)^2 ds < \infty.$$

1) Prove that $H$ is a Hilbert space for the scalar product 
$$(g,h) = \int_0^1 g'(s) h'(s)ds.$$

To show this, I need to show that if $(h_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H$, then it converges in $H$.

The scalar product given means that we have a $L^2$ Cauchy sequence $(h_n')$, and hence by the completeness of $L^2$, we have some $h'\in L^2$ such that $h_n' \to h'$ in the $L^2$ sense. So we can conclude the proof if we show the existence of a continuous function $h$ for which $h(t) - h(0) = h(t) = \int_0^t h'(s)ds$. However, I am stuck at this point. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $|h_{m}(t)-h_{n}(t)|=\left|\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}h_{m}'(s)-h_{n}'(s)ds\right|\leq\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}|h_{m}'(s)-h_{n}'(s)|^{2}ds$, so $h(t)=\lim_{n}h_{n}(t)$ is defined everywhere.

As you have noted that $h_{n}'\rightarrow k$ in $L^{2}$, then $\|h_{n}'-k\|_{L^{1}[0,t]}\leq\|h_{n}'-k\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\rightarrow\infty$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}h_{n}'(s)ds=\int_{0}^{t}k(s)ds$. But $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}h_{n}'(s)ds=h_{n}(t)$ and hence $h(t)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}k(s)ds$.